# How to convert a large stream to a gzipped base64 string

Tags: javascript, node.js, zlib, amazon-athena, node-redis

I'm building an analytics platform and I want to compress my ETL(Extract Transform Load) jobs before I store them in my database. Before I start writing the code, I was wondering if someone with some experience could tell me how to do it properly. I want to gzip the data, and then convert it to a base64 string. Do I simply gzip, and convert to base64 or will that not work?

This is the process I'm currently using for these large datasets.

```
var streamObj = athenaClient.execute('my query').toStream()
var data = [];

redis.set('Some Dashboard Data', '[')

streamObj.on('data', function(record) {
    // TODO gzip record then convert to base64
    if (data.length === 500) {
        let tempData = JSON.stringify(data);
        data = []
        redis.append('Some Dashboard Data', tempData.slice(1, tempData.length - 1) + ',')
        }
        data.push(record);
    })
}
```

If this is not possible, is there a way to store the gzipped string instead?

Comment: why data.length === 500 ? is that how you are splitting the stream?

Comment: Node runs out of memory if I don't do it this way and causes a Stack Overflow ;)

Comment: Could I write it to a temporary file, and then compress the entire file?

Comment: were talking like 20mb of data

Comment: i think inside your if condition, you can try to pause your read stream, do the gzip and base64 conversion save it in redis and on success of that resume the stream. This way you won't be having surplus data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to further elaborate on Zilvinas answer. I will show you all how I got it to work.

```
const athena = require('./athena')
const redis = require('./redis')
const zlib = require('zlib')
const Stream = require('stream')

exports.persistStream = (config, query, name, transform) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let recordCount = 0

    var transformStream = new Stream.Transform({ writableObjectMode: true, readableObjectMode: true})
    transformStream._transform = function (chunk, encoding, done) {

        recordCount++

        if (transform) chunk = transform(chunk)

        let jsonChunk = JSON.stringify([chunk])

        switch (true) {
            case recordCount === 1: 
                jsonChunk = jsonChunk.slice(0, jsonChunk.length - 1); break
            default:
                jsonChunk = ',' + jsonChunk.slice(1, jsonChunk.length - 1); break
        }
        this.push(jsonChunk)
        done();
    };

    transformStream._final = function (done) {
        this.push(']')
        done()
    }

    const gzip = zlib.createGzip()

    let buffers = []

    var stream = athena.execute(query)
        .toStream()
        .pipe(transformStream)
        .pipe(gzip)

    gzip.on('data', (chunk) => {
        buffers.push(chunk)
    })

    gzip.on('end', function () {
        let buffer = Buffer.concat(buffers)
        redis.set(name, buffer.toString('base64'), (err, response) => {
            zlib.gzip(config, (err, buff) => {
                redis.set(name + ' Config', buff.toString('base64'), (err, response) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                        reject()
                    } else {

                        console.log(name + ' succeeded')
                        resolve()
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    })

    stream.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(err)
        reject()
    })
})
}
```

Comment: Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Let node.js environment control memory by using backpressure provided by streams.

I would consider this solution:

```
inputStream
    .pipe(zlib)
    .pipe(transformToBase64Stream)
    .pipe(redisCli);
```

[zlib](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) is native so that should not cause any problems.
To convert to base64 you can write transform stream or use external [tools](https://github.com/mazira/base64-stream#readme). To pipe results into [redis by stream](https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert), you could spawn child process [redis-cli](https://redis.io/topics/rediscli) in pipe mode. As mentioned in mass insertion and redis cli articles it is suggested for big data but you got to handle redis protocol yourself. Read provided articles and let me know if it helped your problem to solve.

Comment: Thank you for this insight. I will try and apply this in a real-life context and then let you know how it goes.